# Two CTEs in one query in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Could we have two CTEs in one query in Postgresql?

Comment: What do you mean? What's the problem you want to solve? How is a CTE "in" a table? What kind of query do you want to run and how do you envision it working?

Comment: yes. I came uo with the solution Thank you

Comment: @user1043898 The examples in the manual cover that rather well. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you meant in one query and not in one table, then yes you can. For example:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    ...
), cte2 AS (
    ...
)
SELECT *
FROM cte1, cte2
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes we could. We could have Nested CTEs like :

```
WITH F AS
(WITH D AS (.....)


SELECT ....


FROM (...)
;
```